# Auto Thread resume c++

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

i build Simple Anticheat module for a game and i need protect the Thread's from a Suspend (Like Suspend Thread from Processhacker).

Is there any way to automatically resume the thread if is suspended?

Here is my module code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Start.h"

void Msg_Sf_Br(){
    MessageBoxA(NULL,"SpeedHack - Detect", load.Nome_das_Janelas, MB_SERVICE_NOTIFICATION | MB_ICONWARNING);
ExitProcess(0);
} 

void Msg_Sf_En(){
    MessageBoxA(NULL,"SpeedHack - Detect", load.Nome_das_Janelas, MB_SERVICE_NOTIFICATION | MB_ICONWARNING);
ExitProcess(0);
}

void Speed_perf()
{
if( *(unsigned long*)QueryPerformanceCounter != 2337669003 ){
if (load.Log_Txt_Hack == 1){
}

    if (load.Message_Warning_En == 1){
    ExitProcess(0); 
}
    if (load.Message_Warning_En == 2){
    CreateThread(NULL,NULL,LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE(Msg_Sf_Br),NULL,0,0);
    Sleep(3000); 
    ExitProcess(0);  
}

    if (load.Message_Warning_En == 0){
    ExitProcess(0);
    }
    else
    ExitProcess(0);
}
}


void performance(){
    if (load.Anti_Kill_Scans == 1)
    {
again:
    Speed_perf();
    Sleep(load.Detecta_Speed_PerformanceT);
    goto again;
}
    else
    {
again2:
    Speed_perf();
    Sleep(load.Detecta_Speed_PerformanceT);
    goto again2;
}
}

void SPerformance(){
    CreateThread(NULL,NULL,LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE(performance),NULL,0,0);
    }
```

Any idea?

Comment: One lazy solution is to poll the time between calls to some known function, and if that time gets out of wack, exit the program or delete the user's personal data.

Comment: Queue a User Mode Asynchronous procedure call or put it on the threadpool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little trick you can hide your thread from any debugger or tools like process hacker.

```
void func() 
{
}

int main()
{
    int(__stdcall* ZwCreateThreadEx)(HANDLE, ACCESS_MASK, POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES, HANDLE, PVOID, PVOID, ULONG, ULONG_PTR, SIZE_T, SIZE_T, PVOID) = (decltype(ZwCreateThreadEx))GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("ntdll.dll"),"ZwCreateThreadEx");
    HANDLE hThread=0;
    ZwCreateThreadEx(&hThread,0x1FFFFF,0,GetCurrentProcess(), 
            (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)func,0, 0x4/*hide flag*/,0,0x1000,0x10000,0);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

- get list of process thread ids, using `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot`
- go to first thread using methods: `Thread32First`.
- for each found thread (you should check if belong to the given process):
- then Open the thread using `OpenThread` in manner to retrieve handle to the thread from it thread id,
- when you have the handle, you can suspend the thread using `SuspendThread` in manner to retrieve the previous suspension count,
- then you can Resume the thread until it suspension count is 0. you must resume at least once in manner to cancel the suspension from the previous step.
- if thread are not allowed to be suspended, you can use `ResumeThread` just to get the suspension count even if it was not suspended.
- Close the thread handle using `CloseHandle`
- iterate to next thread use `Thread32Next`.

### In manner to be able to do the whole thing you must run as administrator.

#### Here is an example:

```
void TraverseProcessThreads(DWORD pid)
{
  HANDLE hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD, 0); //get list of all system thread
  if( hSnapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
  { 
     //print error and return;
     return;
  }
  THREADENTRY32 threadEntry;
  if( Thread32First( hSnapshot, &threadEntry) ) 
  {
     size_t threadsCounter = 0, suspendedThreadsCounter=0;
     do{
       if(te.th32OwnerProcessID == pid) //we get all threads in system, should filter the relevant pid.
       {
         threadsCounter ++; //found thread
         HANDLE hThread = OpenThread(THREAD_ALL_ACCESS,FALSE,te.th32ThreadID); //get  handle to thread from its thread id
         if(hThread == NULL) //
         {
           //print error and break. (will be permission error if not administrator)
           break; 
         }
         int suspensionCount = SuspendThread( hThread ) ;//will return previous suspension count. you can also use ResumeThread if there's no way it can be suspended.
         if(suspensionCount > 0) 
         {
            //thread was suspended 
            suspendedThreadsCounter ++;   
         }
         //cancel our suspension... 
         suspensionCount = ResumeThread(hThread );

         /*to resume suspended thread use ResumeThread until it return 1.
         do{
           suspensionCount = ResumeThread(hThread );
         }while (suspensionCount > 1); //similar to Suspend Resume return previous Suspention count. 
         */   
       }  
       CloseHandle(hThread);      
     }while(Thread32Next( hSnapshot, &threadEntry) );
     //print results:
     cout<<"process id"<<pid<<endl<<" has "<<threadsCounter <<" threads " <<endl
       <<suspendedThreadsCounter <<" threads was suspended"<<endl;
  }
  else{
    //print some error...
  } 
  CloseHandle(hSnapshot);
}
```